# Making Array of Objects for ListView using ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, object, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I seem to be having troubles implementing a list of objects into a simple ListView.

Here is my object class for each of the list elements.
package com.example.android.fragments;

```
package com.example.android.fragments;

public class ListObject {
    public String objectname;   //name of schedule
    public boolean[] Days = {
            false,  //monday
            false,  //tuesday
            false,  //and soforth
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false};

    public int starthour, startminute, stophour, stopminute;    //times from TimePicker
    public boolean vibrate; 

    public ListObject()
    {
        objectname = null; //if doesnt work, do objectname = "";
        vibrate = false;
        starthour = 8;
        startminute = 0;
        stophour = 15;
        stopminute = 0;
    }

    public ListObject(String name, boolean[] newdays, boolean vib, int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        objectname = name;
        Days = newdays;
        vibrate = vib;
        starthour = a;
        startminute = b;
        stophour = c;
        stopminute = d;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String startampm = "am";
        String stopampm = "am";
        if (starthour > 11) //turns into am/pm
        {
            startampm = "pm";
            starthour -= 12;
        }
        if (stophour > 11)  //turns into am/pm
        {
            stopampm = "pm";
            stophour -= 12;
        }

        String daysstring = null ;  //initializes string representing days activated
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)  //add into string the correct days
        {
            if (Days[i] == true)
            {
                if(i == 0)
                    daysstring += "M, ";
                else if (i == 1)
                    daysstring += "Tu, ";
                else if (i == 2)
                    daysstring += "W, ";
                else if (i == 3)
                    daysstring += "Th, ";
                else if (i == 4)
                    daysstring += "F, ";
                else if (i == 5)
                    daysstring += "Sa, ";
                else
                    daysstring += "Su, ";
            }
        }
        daysstring = daysstring.substring(0, daysstring.length() - 3);  //removes the last ', '
        daysstring += ": ";

        String timestring = 
                starthour + ":" + startminute + " " + startampm + " - " + 
                stophour + ":" + stopminute + " " + stopampm;

        return objectname + "\n" + daysstring + timestring;
    }

}
```

My main activity sets the layout to mainlayout which is a FrameLayout

```
package com.example.android.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
        implements MainListFragment.OnListSelectedListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

        // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) { //meaning, if using phone version

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
            MainListFragment firstFragment = new MainListFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
            // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());



            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {

        // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
        InfoFragment articleFrag = (InfoFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);    //article_fragment exists in layout-large

        if (articleFrag != null) {
            // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

            // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

        } else {
            // phone layout - swap frags

            // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
            InfoFragment newFragment = new InfoFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(InfoFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where the problem is, in my ListFragment here which is supposed to be open at the start of the application, I cannot simply create 3 of the objects and put them in the listview defined in my listlayout.xml which has the ListView id of mainlistview

```
package com.example.android.fragments;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainListFragment extends ListFragment{ //used to extend ListActivity{
    OnListSelectedListener mCallback;

    // The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
    public interface OnListSelectedListener {
        /** Called by ListFragment when a list item is selected */
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
        int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;


        //using this now to add properties
        ListView mainlist = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.mainlistview);

        //INFO FOR MADE UP OBJECTS
        boolean[] Days1 = {         
                true,   //monday
                false,  //tuesday
                true,   //and soforth
                false,
                true,
                false,
                false};

        boolean[] Days2 = {
                false,  //monday
                false,  //tuesday
                false,  //and soforth
                false,
                true,
                true,
                true};

        boolean[] Days3 = {
                false,  //monday
                false,  //tuesday
                false,  //and soforth
                true,
                false,
                false,
                false};

        //create sample objects
        ListObject[] scheduleobjs = 
            {
                new ListObject("Club Practice", Days1, true, 1, 0, 5, 25),
                new ListObject("Work", Days2, true, 3, 30, 14, 20),
                new ListObject("Church", Days3, true, 12, 5, 14, 20)
            };

//        String[] liststring = 
//              {
//                  scheduleobjs[0].toString(),
//                  scheduleobjs[1].toString(),
//                  scheduleobjs[2].toString()
//              };
//        ArrayList<ListObject> arraylist;  //add objects to arraylist
//        arraylist.add(scheduleobjs[0]);
//        arraylist.add(scheduleobjs[1]);
//        arraylist.add(scheduleobjs[2]);

        String[] arraylist = new String[]
                {
                    scheduleobjs[0].toString(),
                    scheduleobjs[1].toString(),
                    scheduleobjs[2].toString()
                };

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, layout, arraylist);
//        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, ))
        mainlist.setAdapter(arrayadapter);

        //inflate here???
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
        // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
//        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment) != null) {
//            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); COMMENTED OUT BECAUSE USED IN 2 PANE LAYOUT
//        }
    }

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
    try {
        mCallback = (OnListSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnListSelectedListener");
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Notify the parent activity of selected item
        mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

        // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
}
```

You can see I have commented out previous attempts at doing this using the object classes' overridden toString(), where am I going wrong and what is the best way to implement this? I am wanting to eventually create a better listview since this only displays a string, and I want different sized and colored text with a checkbox for each object,  but for now I am just trying to get this working.

Comment: Have you tried implementing your own ArrayAdapter.

Comment: What exactly happens when you run your code? Does it crash? Does it show an empty/blank screen? From quickly looking at your ListFragment class you never override onCreateView to load your fragment layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter.
Here you have an example: http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/